# HAProxy 1.7 Redirect/Rewrite specific domains with Map Files

Tags: linux, http, haproxy

I am new to HAProxy and I would like to redirect requests in map files defined domains.
An short example:
In my redirect.map file:

```
abc.com xyz.com
def.ru idk.com
```

So if the user sends a request to domain abc.com or def.ru he will be redirected to the defined domain. But if he requests asd.com, no redirect should be done.
My aim is to define those redirects in a map file so it is easy to change.

Next i would like to do the same with uri rewrites.
Something like:

```
http-request set-uri X if Y from rewrite.map
```

So my Map file will look like:

```
 (my X variable)    (my Y variable)
/abc/def/specific  www.mydomain.com/specific
```

Do I even have the opportunity to do this with HAProxy?

Comment: Yes, this is likely possible, but you need to define what it means when you say *"he will be directed to the defined domain."* Did you mean *redirected*, as in HTTP redirect?

Comment: oh.. *redirect sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http-request redirect location https://%[hdr(host),map(/etc/haproxy/rewrite.map)]%[capture.req.uri] code 301 if { hdr(host),map(/etc/haproxy/rewrite.map) -i -m found }
```

The [`hdr(x)` fetch](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-hdr) reads the request header `x` and returns the value found.  (Technically, it reads the last occurrence of this header, but the `Host` header should only appear once.)

The [`map` converter](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.1-map) takes the value preceding it (connected with `,`), looks it up in the map table, and returns the result.

If no match is found, no result is returned, so the `-m found` test returns no result and the rule is not matched.  (`-i` makes the lookup case-insensitive).

If the rule is matched, we build a new URL for the `Location` response header, using the literal string `https://` (change this to `http` if appropriate) + the rewritten hostname from the map file + the original request URI, which begins with the leading `/` and includes the path and query string, preserving the entire request URI.

If you don't want to preserve the original URI, but just send everything to the main page of the target site, then remove `%[capture.req.uri]` from the expression.

Comment: is it even possible to match both with and without trailing slash on request.uri ?